# AngularJS UI-Grid Programmatically set dirty flag for saving in rowEdit feature

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I have an AngularJS UI-Grid with rowEdit feature enabled.
I need to programmatically notify that a row changed value and need to be saved (because this change was made to the model externally to the grid).
How can this be achieved?

For references:
http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/205_row_editable

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/api/ui.grid.rowEdit.api:PublicApi.

The method you want is setRowsDirty, so it would be:

```
$scope.gridApi.rowEdit.setRowsDirty( rows );
```

You'd need to have got the gridApi first from onRegisterApi.